# Webstorm's build-in web server file caching settings?

Tags: google-chrome, caching, webserver, webstorm

**Tools**: JetBrains' Webstorm 10.0.4 -its a pretty fresh install and no plug-ins. Chrome Version 43. The project is vanilla html, css and js.

**Issue**: While local debugging, Files sometimes cache when using the built-in web server (I click run and opens Chrome to a URL that has the form: "http://localhost:[Port]/[ProjectName]/index.html"). Pressing f5 will show the cached version but cntl-f5 will fetch the current.

**Detail**: The request header contains "Cache-Control:max-age=0" (meaningless?). Opening the file in Chrome with "file:///C:/Users/[Username]/WebstormProjects/WebLayout/index.html" doesn't seem to have this problem but f5 on the web server version will still yield the cached version.

**Attempts**:

1. Editing run/debug config. I see nothing related to what I'm looking for.
2. I tried finding web server settings to set response headers manually. "File" > "Settings" >> "Build Execution Deployment" > "Deployment" has no servers configured. I think this is for pushing remotely.

**Speculation**: Chrome is caching Webstorm's web server files because it isn't setting "no-cache" response headers. I can't find where/how to set those options.

**Current Fix**:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

**Sample Headers**:
General:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:9129
Request URL:http://localhost:9129/WebLayout/index.html
    Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

Response Headers:

```
cache-control:private, must-revalidate
content-length:5674
Content-Type:text/html
date:Mon, 13 Jul 2015 20:43:19 GMT
last-modified:Mon, 13 Jul 2015 01:45:23 GMT
server:WebStorm 10.0.4
```

Request Headers:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
DNT:1
Host:localhost:9129
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) ... Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: I have the same problem. WebStorm's server keeps responding with old versions of JS files which I already modified. Clearing cache didn't help. I even remove files from filesystem, but WebStorm still keeps responding as if nothing happened.

Comment: My issue was with the browser. Are you editing the files while the web storms server is running?

Comment: Maybe, not sure, but I was even trying to clear WebStorm's server's cache (it also makes WebStorm to restart) - didn't help. For now the only way to fix it I found so far is to rename file to something else and then rename back.

Comment: So you tried Clearing the browser's Cache, the Server's cache, restarting the webserver? Are you on windows?

Comment: Have you tried adding unnecessary query strings to your JS URL? "//localhost/folder/myfile.js?t=1"

Answer (score 0):

WebStorm built-in server send
1) cache-control: "private, must-revalidate"
2) last-modified: file last modified.

I see two possible reasons:
1) WebStorm sends incorrect file last modified (we use virtual file system). Is index.html edited inside WebStorm or outside?
2) Maybe it is Google Chrome bug. In this case we can add option to disable "if modified since" support and always send "Expires: 0".

Could you please inspect network headers?

Comment: I only used WebStorm to edit. I added sample headers to the post.

The run config says it is the Javascript Debug option. I doubt it was chrome. Any idea to change settings of the built-in webserver?

Answer (score 0):

If you load an older version of the same project, you consistently have this problem.

From the testing I did, I think this is what happesn:
The webserver identifies the files by module (project) name and relative path and caches them. So if you have two projects with the same name on different locations on your system both have a file (e.g. JS) with the same relative path, for the internal webserver they are the same file. So if you run an html file in project 1 that uses a javascript file, and project 2 happens to have the same file with a more recent timestamp, the HTML page of project 1 will load the javascript file of project 2.

The caching even survives restart with clear all caches of webstorm.

To avoid the problem you could try these

```
- rename your project (may give a 404 on running the webpage if the other project is still open)
- make a small change in the file (often the cache will see that your file is newer than what's in the cache).
```